# Define TypeSpec from TypeRef for .Net IL

Tags: c++, .net, metadata, clr-profiling-api

I have built custom IL Rewriter that inject custom code into some methods. Part of this injection, I want to instantiate the object of `List<int>`. I already found the mdTokenRef for List~1.

From this mdTokenRef, how do I define or obtain TypeSpec? I could define the TypeSpecBlog as shown below for that. But, looking for an ICorProfiler API to find the TypeSpec.

```
COR_SIGNATURE sigListInt[] = { ELEMENT_TYPE_GENERICINST, ELEMENT_TYPE_CLASS, tdList, 0x01, ELEMENT_TYPE_I1 };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't define TypeSpec from mdTokenRef, but you can use IMetaDataEmit object and define your TypeSpec via GetTokenFromTypeSpec function.

To get IMetaDataEmit object, you may use IMetaDataImport, that provides QueryInterface function

```
IMetaDataImport* mdImport;
....
IMetaDataEmit* mdEmit;
HRESULT hr = mdImport->QueryInterface(IID_IMetaDataEmit, (void**)&mdEmit);
```